# Determine whether $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac n{n^2\sqrt n+1}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac n{n^2\sqrt n+1}$$
I tried to use the ratio test but my answer is 1 and that gives no information about the answer. I have also used the root test and the given answer is 1. How could I determine the convergence or divergence of this series? I have also tried to use the integral test and the answer is too long and to difficult.

Comment: The fraction in the question body has an $n^2$ in the denominator, while the fraction in the title doesn't. Which one is correct?

Comment: different series in title and body.

Comment: The one in the body is the correct one

Comment: Limit comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$ \frac{n}{(n^2 {\sqrt n} +1)}\sim \frac1{n\sqrt n}$$

then use limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n\sqrt n}$ to show convergence.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_n \frac{n}{n^{5/2}+1} \le \sum_n \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} < \infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac n{n^2\sqrt n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n^2\sqrt n+1}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n^2\sqrt n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}=\zeta(3/2)^*<\infty$$

*The series representation $\zeta(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-x}$ is convergent for all $x>1$.

Comment: Can I ask you what kind of methode is used?

Comment: @nguyen_25 Limit comparison test, of course.

Comment: does this mean that the serie converges?

Comment: @nguyen_25 Yes.